# Ruby on Rails - Inheritance - User Accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a website where users can create an Account. Each Account will have Settings. Settings will have different types of Settings such as General and Privacy.

What is the best way to organize a Rails application with this kind of framework in mind? Should I be taking advantage of inheritance with this, or should I just be making a huge MySQL database for Account which has values for General Settings, Privacy Settings, etc?

I know Java well, and if I had to do this in Java I would be using inheritance. But I am just beginning learning Ruby on Rails, so I figured I would ask this question on here for a better understanding of how inheritance with RoR works.

Comment: well keep in mind Ruby on Rails is just a framework written in Ruby.  just like Java, ruby has inheritance as well.

Comment: There's gonna be a ton of online research on this topic, including plugins for Rails, if you e-search for "user roles". "Roles" is the common industry term for those permission levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an User, Account and Setting model like this

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_one :account

end
```

account.rb

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_one :setting   

end
```

setting.rb

```
class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_one :general_setting
    has_one :privacy_setting 
    .
    .

end
```